# Multiple System.out.println() calls showing up on one line?

Tags: java, error-handling

This program gives some weird output. After many executions of this loop, I see a single line of output with the contents of three separate .println() functions. Why does this happen?

Caution: This program runs in an infinite loop.

````````
public class Looping
{
    static int i;
    public static void main(String agrs[])
    {
        try
        {
            i++;
            System.out.println("In try String agrs" +i +" ");
            main(i);
            System.out.println(i+"After main(i).**************************!!!!!!!~~~~~~~~~~~~~```````++++_(^&$^%&%$#%$^$#%^&Y%$^#%^%&@#%#$%");
        }
        catch(Error e)
        {

            System.out.println("Catch reached"+i);
            Looping q=new Looping();
            q.main(++i);
        }
    }

    public static void main(int k)
    {
        try
        {
            i++;
            System.out.println("In try int k -- " +i +" __ ");
            main(i);
            System.out.println(i+"After main(i).**************************!!!!!!!~~~~~~~~~~~~~```````++++_(^&$^%&%$#%$^$#%^&Y%$^#%^%&@#%#$%");
        }
        catch(Error e)
        {
            System.out.println("Catch of int k -- " + i + " Why there is no new line here???______");
            i++;
            System.out.println("i increasing done.. next executes main(++i)");
            main(++i);
        }
    }
}
````````

Here's the output (with some intermediary lines deleted):

```
In try String agrs1 
In try int k -- 2 __ 
In try int k -- 3 __ 
In try int k -- 4 __ 
In try int k -- 5 __ 
In try int k -- 6 __ 
In try int k -- 7 __ 
In try int k -- 8 __ 
In try int k -- 9 __ 
...
...
...
...
..
...
In try int k -- 2889 __ 
In try int k -- 2890 __ 
In try int k -- 2891 __ 
Catch of int k -- 2891 Why there is no new line here???______
i increasing done.. next executes main(++i)
In try int k -- 2894 __ Catch of int k -- 2894 Why there is no new line here???______Catch of int k -- 2894 Why there is no new line here???______
i increasing done.. next executes main(++i)
In try int k -- 2897 __ 
In try int k -- 2898 __ Catch of int k -- 2898 Why there is no new line here???______Catch of int k -- 2898 Why there is no new line here???______
i increasing done.. next executes main(++i)
In try int k -- 2901 __ 
In try int k -- 2902 __ Catch of int k -- 2902 Why there is no new line here???______Catch of int k -- 2902 Why there is no new line here???______
i increasing done.. next executes main(++i)
In try int k -- 2905 __ Catch of int k -- 2905 Why there is no new line here???______
Catch of int k -- 2905 Why there is no new line here???______
i increasing done.. next executes main(++i)
In try int k -- 2908 __ 
In try int k -- 2909 __ 
In try int k -- 2910 __ Catch of int k -- 2910 Why there is no new line here???______Catch of int k -- 2910 Why there is no new line here???______
i increasing done.. next executes main(++i)
In try int k -- 2913 __ 
In try int k -- 2914 __ Catch of int k -- 2914 Why there is no new line here???______Catch of int k -- 2914 Why there is no new line here???______
i increasing done.. next executes main(++i)
In try int k -- 2917 __ Catch of int k -- 2917 Why there is no new line here???______
Catch of int k -- 2917 Why there is no new line here???______
i increasing done.. next executes main(++i)
In try int k -- 2920 __ 
In try int k -- 2921 __ 
In try int k -- 2922 __ 
....
.....
..
```

Comment: Why are your trying to put your JVM under pressure with this infinite loop?

Comment: This example is completely useless, can someone explain me the usefulness of this code?

Comment: I was trying some other stuff... I was surprised by the output and then became curious.. Thats all..

Comment: Can you give your output, and what you expected the output to be?

Comment: Infinite loops are not so appreciated by your machine...

Comment: @David Jones .. Yup.. Wait!!

Comment: I have added the output...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An exception is being thrown within the `println()` library function.

After instrumenting, I see this:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError

java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder.encode(CharsetEncoder.java:579)
sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implWrite(StreamEncoder.java:271)
sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:125)
java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(OutputStreamWriter.java:207)
java.io.BufferedWriter.flushBuffer(BufferedWriter.java:129)
java.io.PrintStream.write(PrintStream.java:526)
java.io.PrintStream.print(PrintStream.java:669)
java.io.PrintStream.println(PrintStream.java:823)
Looping.main(Looping.java:41)
```

You're not just looping infinitely, you're in an infinite nested call.  That fills up the call stack, which is used by both your program and any library calls you make.  As the `println()` call goes about its work, it's making calls itself.  At some point, it runs out of stack space and the exception is thrown.  That takes you out of the existing `catch` clause and up into the next-higher nested `catch` clause.

Comment: How is the println() nested ??

Comment: It's not the `println()` that's nested, it's all the calls to `Looping.main()`

Comment: Ops! I got it wrong.. So if we call any other library function after the error has occurred for the first time, another error would be thrown in the catch block when another function like println() is called from the catch block.

Comment: If you run out of stack space (through, say, infinite recursion) than any call that you make, library or no, will cause another error to be thrown.   In your particular case, the stack still has enough space to admit the overhead of the `println()` call, but gets filled up during the `println()` call itself.

Comment: Because you are nesting calls through recursion, you are also nesting `catch` blocks.  So the error is caught by the same `catch` block, one level up the stack.